# How do I encrypt multiple passwords using one key?

Tags: java, android

I want to encrypt multiple passwords using one key using Java. I can generate passwords using a key generator but it generates different key every time.
I want only one key to do encryption. How do I encrypt multiple passwords using one key?
And the other issue is each time i run my application i always use the same key after i re-start application.

Comment: Can you post the code you have running

Comment: Can you also please clarify if you have all the passwords available at the same time? If so then I would use tskuzzy's method.

Comment: Yes i have all the password at same time in my database.

Comment: @Martyn:Actually I don't know the code.

Comment: Why are you doing this? You shouldn't be encrypting passwords at all, and you shouldn't have them in plaintext in the first place. Passwords should be hashed.

Comment: That depends on the usage, if you're remembering a password in an application then a hash is no good to you. As this is tagged Android I think that might be quite likely.

Comment: Re-reading the post, EJP is right in that you shouldn't be storing plaintext passwords in a database. And if you are using the database to check passwords (as opposed to storing them to automatically log in), then hashing is the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate a key based on a set passphrase you will get given the same key (if all other key-related parameters are the same). If you can edit your question to give more information about what encryption algorithm you want to use I might be able to help more.

---

**Edit:** Okay, here's some example code to generate a key based on a passphrase (so as to get the same key each time):

```
// 16 characters for 128-bit AES
private final static String PASSPHRASE="myappspassphrase"

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(PASSPHRASE.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

...

// Initialise the cipher
Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
```

Comment: Yes u can help me in that way also.

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you help me if i write in one function what does it returns?

Comment: When i use this code i return byte[]. Then i convert this byte[] into the String and it gives me output like ?? then some bxes. Please tell e what to do now.

Comment: If you combine my code with tskuzzy's answer then you should have what you want. Have `generateKey()` return a `SecretKeySpec`, initialise the `Cipher` with it as I showed you, then use the `for-each` loop in tskuzzy's answer to encrypt the passwords one by one and store them in an array.

Comment: The best thing to do is to not encode to a String. The output will be indecipherable anyway (those weird characters you mentioned - that is expected output), but the conversions can cause issues. If you use `context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` you can write the byte array directly to your application's private storage.
If you _must_ encode to a String, use a `Base64` encoder, though I had issues when doing this and using `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate a key `k`
2. Loop through your passwords (call a password `p`)
3. Encrypt each `p` with `k` using an encryption scheme of your choice

Now just define `generateKey()` and `encrypt(String password, String key)`

```
String key = generateKey();
String[] encrypted = new String[passwords.length];

for( String password : passwords )
    encrypted = encrypt( password, key );
```

Comment: Can you give the executable code here??? I am still not clear.Because generatekey() is i think going to generate everytime  i run the application. So the key might be change.